# Principal axis form of Inertia tensor with eigen

Tags: eigen, tensor, axes, principal

I want to compute the principal axis form of an inertia tensor that stays consistent with changes of the inertia. Currently eigen outputs the computed eigenvalues(Ia,Ib,Ic) from smallest to largest, which scrambles the order of the x,y and z inertia moments. This doesn't allow me to map the eigenvalues directly to the diagonal inertia tensor.

To start, I have a multibody system for which I calculate the inertia moments Ixx, Iyy, Izz and products Ixy, Ixz, Iyz around the center of mass. From here I construct a 3x3 inertia matrix. This inertia is in coordinate frame A and can have non-zero off-diagonal components. I can observe this inertia matrix change continuously depending on the movement of my bodies.

For example, initially my computed inertia looks something like this:
0.25 0 0
0 0.22 0
0 0 0.02

then the eigenvalues look something like this:
0.02
0.22
0.25

and the eigenvectors look something like this:
0 0 1
0 1 0
1 0 0

As you can see, the eigensolver sorts the eigenvalues in ascending order, which results in a Izz,Iyy,Ixx vector, which isn't the desired Ixx,Iyy,Izz order.
As I move the bodies around, the inertia changes and so does the ordering of the eigenvalues (Ixx,Iyy and Izz can easily swap places). Two of these eigenvalues can stay constant, while the third one changes so much that it influences the ordering. I would like to find the mapping that keeps the values consistent - achieve always a Ixx,Iyy and Izz order of my eigenvalues.

Comment: What is the "principal axis" if not the axis which corresponds to the largest eigenvalue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eigenvalues quantify inertia along principal axes, their ordering is irrelevant as long as the correspondance with eigenvectors is preserved. Don't be confused by the fact that they are equal to diagonal Ixx,Iyy,Izz elements in your example, the eigenvalues have nothing to do with x-y-z coordinates, in particular, they are orientation-agnostic. If you want to compare inertias of different body configurations, you have to take into account the eigenvectors as well, e.g., draw ellipsoids.

Comment: This is precisely what I am trying to do. I get the eigenvalues and their corresponding eigenvectors. I use the eigenvectors as the rotation matrix between my coordinate frames and then plot the ellipsoid. However the drawn ellipsoid is often changing its orientation making the visualisation not continuous

Comment: The only way ordering may mess you up that comes to my mind is that eigenvectors may form an improper rotation matrix. Check its determinant and reshuffle vectors if necessary.

Comment: The `SelfAdjointEigenSolver` should always generate a unitarian Eigenvector matrix (which is not necessary a rotation). Another possible source of error is that it may be necessary to multiply with the adjoint (i.e., the inverse) of the Eigenvectormatrix (depends on how you define your coordinate systems)

Comment: I always verify that the rotation matrix is a proper one by doing R^T*R == Identity, so far never had an improper one.

Comment: Improper rotations are a special kind of matrices, they satisfy this property as well, e.g., [1, 0, 0; 0, -1, 0; 0, 0, 1]. You can fix it like this: [0, -1, 0; 1, 0, 0; 0, 0, 1].

Comment: I noticed that the improper rotations started happening when the tilt around any arbitrary axis was greater than approximately 80 degrees. I decided to try a different approach - it is somewhat of a workaround. Instead of calculating the inertia using the global orientation, I use the previous Inertia PA orientation. This way my calculated inertia is always somewhat close to the PA form, and rotations are small enough. This totally removed the problem and I now have a perfect and consistent inertia tensor in principal axis form. Thank you for the help everybody.